# Variable shared between view controllers of storyboard?

Tags: swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults

My app is split into 2 storyboards: a character selection one and a main application one. When the user selects a character the app segues's to the main application, and all the views of that storyboard should now relate to the character the user selected.

I'm trying to find out the best way to share a String that will have the selected character's information between all the main application storyboard's views. Right now I'm using `UserDefaults` to just set a global variable:

```
func loadMainApp(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let currentCharcter = allCharacters[(sender.view?.tag)!]
    let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.setValue(currentCharacter, forKey: "CurrentCharacter")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainAppSegue", sender: self)       
}
```

From there all the view controllers in the Main App storyboard can fetch the string from `UserDefaults`.

Is this the best way of doing such a thing or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to pass the character to the viewController you are segueing to, and the easiest way to do that is with `prepare(for segue`.  If you change your `performSegue` call to pass the sender on by saying `performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainAppSegue", sender: sender)` you will be able to access that in `prepare(for` like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    //Safely check to make sure this is the correct segue by unwrapping the sender and checking the segue identifier
    if let tapGesture = sender as? UITapGestureRecognizer, let tapGestureView = sender.view, let mainViewController = segue.destination as? MainViewController, segue.identifier == "MainAppSegue" {

        //Get a reference to the character that was selected
        let currentCharacter = allCharacters[tapGestureView.tag]

        //Pass the character to the new viewController
        mainViewController.character = currentCharacter
    }
}
```

I made a couple assumptions about the name of the viewController you are performing the segue to, and assumed it has a variable called `character` where you can send your character.  Your new viewController now has a reference to the character.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well. Personally I am using Singeltons for achieving Global variable between Views rather than UserDefaults

```
class SomeClass{
static let sharedInstance = SomeClass()
var someString = "This String is same from any class"
}

Usage inside of some function :
SomeClass.sharedInstance.someString  = "Changing Global String"
```